# Why are my Android SDK package files missing after relocating SDK?

Tags: android, sdk, package

I have recently changed the location of my android SDK location from inside the android folder to the desktop. Now the one or two build-tools show in the SDK manager but the rest of the packages which I used to have such as Android 6 (API 23) and Android 5 (API 22) show as uninstalled. I cannot for the life of me locate where these files are including searching C drive and Program files/Android...
. Does anyone know where these packages went?

Comment: is your issue fixed?

Comment: Yes I copied all the SDK folders across to new SDK folder location and used the windows folder merge function to create one SDK folder

Answer (score 0):

I realise that the windows file "AppData" is hidden in windows 10 and this is where the sdk files are located. If they are not copied across to new location when relocating your SDK you may copy them across manually from this location.